# How to make Pandas bar char add X axis labels to transposed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, charts

I bar chart that I am creating with Pandas. The plot display the label on the X axis. How do I get the chart to display the expected labels?

```py
import pandas as pd

metrics_1_csv = Path("/tmp/metrics_2.csv")
print("reading", metrics_1_csv)
df = pd.read_csv(metrics_1_csv)

df = df.groupby(["transaction"]).sum(numeric_only=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=["duration"], ascending=False)
ax = df.transpose().plot.bar(
    stacked=False,
    title="Duration by Transaction",
    figsize=(8, 4))
ax.legend(loc='right')
```

This produces the following chart, note that the X label is just "duration", but I'd expect it to say "ddd  bbb cccc aaa eee".
[image]

The data looks like this:

```
transaction,duration
aaa,12451
aaa,8388
aaa,7267
aaa,14852
bbb,10752
bbb,29139
bbb,5694
bbb,7942
bbb,441
bbb,34491
bbb,25707
bbb,14609
ccc,8035
ccc,14772
ccc,8178
ccc,13672
ccc,7792
ccc,18970
ccc,9190
ccc,16020
ccc,5726
ccc,12720
ddd,366
ddd,29148
ddd,10511
ddd,12349
ddd,8560
ddd,2287
ddd,21380
ddd,26270
ddd,12041
ddd,11331
ddd,7277
eee,8854
eee,9090
```

Comment: For plotting long data, [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) provides better APIs and customizations.

Comment: With pandas built-in API: `df.groupby('transaction')['duration'].sum().plot.bar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Transposing the data does not make sense in this context.

What you want to do is just a regular bar plot (assuming that you want the labels across the x axis).

The reason why is because the x-axis refers to the `transaction` categories.

So this will work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import io

data = """
transaction,duration
aaa,12451
aaa,8388
aaa,7267
aaa,14852
bbb,10752
bbb,29139
bbb,5694
bbb,7942
bbb,441
bbb,34491
bbb,25707
bbb,14609
ccc,8035
ccc,14772
ccc,8178
ccc,13672
ccc,7792
ccc,18970
ccc,9190
ccc,16020
ccc,5726
ccc,12720
ddd,366
ddd,29148
ddd,10511
ddd,12349
ddd,8560
ddd,2287
ddd,21380
ddd,26270
ddd,12041
ddd,11331
ddd,7277
eee,8854
eee,9090
"""



# Read text data into DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=",")
df['duration'] = pd.to_numeric(df['duration'])

df = df.groupby(["transaction"]).sum(numeric_only=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=["duration"], ascending=False)
ax = df.plot.bar(
    stacked=False,
    title="Duration by Transaction",
    figsize=(8, 4))
ax.legend(loc='right')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=0)


plt.show()
```

which produces this chart:
[image]